# ImageView present, but not visible in display

Tags: android, xml, imageview, display

I am trying to display an `ImageView` over the intersection of two `RelativeView's`, but am running into some issues.

I have added the `ImageView` and the adjustment borders show up and allow me to constrain and resize the element, but it is not visible. If I put the `ImageView` inside one of the `RelativeView's` then the image will show up, but I cannot overlap the intersection of the two `RelativeView's` like I am wanting to.

In this screenshot here, you can see the `ImageView` is present and overlapping the middle of the screen, but no image is showing.

[image]

And this is my entire `.xml`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_inference"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="351dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/spinner" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorCoral">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="199dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="199dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1Tracker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="154dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="154dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trackbox" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="139dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="139dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="137dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernamep1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="156dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernamep2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="253dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="156dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle4"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1circle3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1circle3"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/p1Tracker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="154dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="154dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trackbox" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="138dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="138dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="138dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The image in question is titled `spinner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imageview you want to display on top needs to be relative to one of the views not to the edge of the parent. It is where you want it to be, but behind both your relativeviews ie you need to be Centring to the edge of a sibling. Also set elevation property to make sure it's on top.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/siblingRelativeView1"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/siblingRelativeView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

This gif demos the concept for a textview to center of imageview, what you want is to center the top to the first relativeview and bottom to second relative view.

[image: Centering to sibling view]

Try to read [this](https://constraintlayout.com/tricks/centring.html).